# While-Loop works but not the if statement?

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, if-statement, while-loop

I have this `while` loop in my code. The loop seems to work fine since I printed my `i++` in the console. But for some reason it only checks my `if` statement the first time around. I can only add one title into the `NSMutableArray` called `sectionZeroTitleArray`. I have many arrays in this loop so it might get confusing. I will try my best to explain.

Here is what I am trying to do:
Loop through the length of an array(topicArray). If the array's(topicArray)is the same as this other array's(anotherArray) first object then add an object that has the same index(titleArray) as topicArray to a new MutableArray(sectionZeroTitleArray).

I'm sure I did something stupid, maybe someone that hasn't stared at this all day can fix me up? Please and thank you.

```
while (i < (topicArray.count)) {
  if ([topicArray objectAtIndex:i] == [anotherArray objectAtIndex:0]) {
   [sectionZeroTitleArray addObject:[titleArray objectAtIndex:i]];
  }
  NSLog(@"sectionZeroLoopCount: %d", i);
  i++;
 }
```

Comment: Add the following before the if statement: `NSLog(@"topicArray value:%@, anotherArray value:%@", [topicArray objectAtIndex:1], [anotherArray objectAtIndex:0]);`

Comment: Does your topicArray contain the exact same object twice? If not, it's quite natural, that it goes only once into the if-brackets. Sure, you don't mean "objectAtIndex:i"?

Comment: Also, what are the types of the objects stored in the arrays? Often, you want to use isEqual: or isEqualToString: rather than ==.

Comment: You have to define what you mean by "is the same as" means. Right now you have written == which means that the pointers point to the same object (the pointers have the same value).

Comment: DUDE, you guys are sick, lol I posted like 5 mins ago and everyone already have the answer. I love this community and you guys are all awesome. If I could, I would give you all check marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are checking for **pointer equality** when you use `==`. Are you sure you want to do this? What is the type that you're expecting? If it's a `NSString`, use `isEqualToString:`, otherwise use `NSObject`'s `isEqual:` method:

If the expected type is an `NSString`:

```
if([[topicArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[anotherArray objectAtIndex:0]]) {
   //...
}
```

Otherwise, you should probably do this:

```
if([[topicArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:[anotherArray objectAtIndex:0]]) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you're comparing the pointers and not the values. Look at the documentation of `NSString`, particular the `isEqualToString:` method for comparing strings.